# Edit ScriptCase Code Directly?

Tags: php, scripting

I'm doubting since this site is full of experts anyone has dealt with this, but I'm hoping someone might have. I'm working with a client now who is creating a site using ScriptCase. I've tried figuring it out, and I'm lost as to how I can do something as simple as parse a CSV file after its been uploaded. So, I'm wondering if anyone knows if I can just edit the source code directly and create the PHP code manually, or if that's even possible using this POS? Thanks!

Comment: It seems to spit out PHP. Go for it.

Comment: Yeah, I finally found where the actual PHP is located, so I can probably edit it. Every time I edit something within it, it says "Generating Source Code," so I'm wary that it might overwrite source code. Guess I'll report back and let everyone know how it goes in case anyone else has to deal with this garbage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can modify as much as you want, but everytime you regenrate de source code it will overwrite your modifications.

Answer (score 1):

The source code is pretty convoluted for ordinary mortals.  What we do is extend it or override it using PHP libraries.

Can also include directly to a library folder

Use Kint (Google) to debug -- it's a lifesaver